# Convert int to float Activerecord query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

When writing a SQL statement you can easily convert an int to a float by multiplying by 1.0 or dividing by some decimal. Example:

`Select dollars_in_cents from myTable;` => `Select dollars_in_cents / 100.0 from myTable;`

However, when writing an Activerecord query I'm not able to do this. When I write

`myTable.select('dollars_in_cents/100.0')`

This returns for my objects' `dollars_in_cents` field as `nil`. Is there any way to convert all properties and stats on the fly?

Comment: You should be able to see, in your log, what the generated sql is for this rails command, which will help you diagnose the problem.  I suspect that it is converting it to `select \`dollars_in_cents/100.0\` from \`mytable\``

Comment: This is what I see `SELECT dollars_in_cents/100.0 FROM "myTable"`

Comment: And if you copy that into your sql console, you get a different result to when the above is done in rails?  Does it make any difference to use double quotes, like `myTable.select("dollars_in_cents/100.0")`

Comment: Tried the double quote thing - nothing new. If I copy and run the SQL statement above then it returns fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha, found it.  When you do `select` with Rails you get a different kind of object back: it looks like a user but its instance variables (the private ones which are accessed by the setter and getter methods) are only set according to the contents of the select, and it sets them **using the names of the fields in the select**: in this case "dollars_in_cents/100.0" - this means there is now an instance variable called "dollars_in_cents/100.0" inside the object you get back.  So, i'd expect to see these results:

```
user = myTable.select("dollars_in_cents/100.0").first
=> #<User >
user.send("dollars_in_cents/100.0")
=> <the right value>
```

the best way to deal with this is to use "as", like so:

```
user = myTable.select("dollars_in_cents/100.0 as dollars").first
=> #<User >
user.dollars
=> <the right value>
```

Comment: I'm not sure the `user.send` works - I wasn't able to get the output from the naming, but the solution does work. I'd like to know why though.

Comment: In the second solution, do you get a different result from `user.send("dollars")` and `user.dollars`? To be honest,  the functionality around `select` feels like quite a dirty, bodgy aspect of Rails to me, i would maybe refactor to avoid it if i was you.

Comment: I'm actually doing this to write an API query

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what point you were trying to make with the last comment.